# How to detect change within JSON object?

Tags: json, qt, qml, signals

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property var json: {
        "name": "old"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: json.name = "new"

    onJsonChanged: console.log("Changed to : " + json.name)

    Button {
        onClicked: console.log("Button clicked: " + json.name)
    }
}
```

```
qml: Changed to : old
```

But I'd expect an output of:

```
qml: Changed to : old
qml: Changed to : new
```

QML has no problem recognizing the `onJsonChanged:` signal, but the signal doesn't actually seem to activate. I know `json.name` is successfully changing, because I've debugged during runtime and see that it has the new value. So why doesn't the signal activate, and/or how can I detect the change in the json object?

Comment: The onJsonChanged signal is activated when the assigned object changes, not when the internal elements since the object is the same (points to the same memory location), for example if you change to the following you should detect the change: ```Component.onCompleted: json = {"name3": "foo"}

    onJsonChanged: console.log("Changed to : " + json)

    Button {
        onClicked: console.log("Button clicked: " + json)
    }```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. If you mark it as an answer I'd gladly accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal associated with the X property is emitted when the object changes, in your case changing some internal attribute does not change the object (the memory space) only modifies internal properties. To verify this you can modify your example to:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property var json: {
        "name": "bar"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: json = {"name3": "foo"}

    onJsonChanged: console.log("Changed to : " + json)

    Button {
        onClicked: console.log("Button clicked: " + json)
    }
}
```

The following is obtained:

```
qml: Changed to : [object Object]
qml: Changed to : [object Object]
```